# Requiring Other Directive controller in child Directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-controller

I have a `questionnaireItem` Directive defined in the template for the `questionnaireItemsGroup` Directive.
In the `questionnaireItem` directive I require `"^questionnaireItemsGroup"`

The parent form:

```
<form name="questionnaireForm" autocomplete="off" novalidate>
  <ol>
    <li>
      <questionnaire-items-group data-ng-model="questionnaireItemsGroupModel">
      </questionnaire-items-group>
    </li>
  </ol>
</form>
```

`questionnaireItemsGroup` template:

```
<div>
  <ol class="">
    <li class="mm-li" ng-repeat="questionnaireItem in model.questionnaireItems">
      <questionnaire-item data-ng-model="questionnaireItem" view-state="{{viewState}}">
      </questionnaire-item>
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Require in the `questionnaireItem` Directive:

```
require: ['?ngModel', '^questionnaireItemsGroup'],
```

I get the error:

> Error: [$compile:ctreq] Controller 'questionnaireItemsGroup', required by directive 'questionnaireItem', can't be found!

Requiring a `ngModel` or `form` controller isn't an issue, done this several times before. The parameter controller in the `link` function of the Directive then consists of an array of controllers.

--But this should work for including/requiring Directives as well right? Am I overlooking something?

Comment: what is `actizQuestionnaireItem`? The error is about some other directive that you are not showing here

Comment: that was a project specific reference, which is removed now. updated the error msg >> 'questionnaireItem', can't be found!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to guess, since the code you posted doesn't show it, that the problem is that your directive `questionnaireItemsGroup` does not define a controller:

```
.directive("questionnaireItemsGroup", function(){
  return {
    controller: angular.noop, // this should fix it
    // ...
  };
});
```

Comment: Sharp, assumed this would do the trick, but still getting he same error, strange enough.

Comment: Then something else is going on. Here's a rudimentary implementation of your directives that works: http://plnkr.co/edit/RedBMdgoXAfIQTepFH8w?p=preview

Comment: @SanJayFalcon, did you fix your issue?

Comment: Example works for me and we found that indeed something else was blocking the correct working. Thx!